# Make Custom Project template in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, templates, project

I have been using Eclipse IDE for a long time. Its a really great IDE for Java/C/C++ (and other languages with its THOUSANDS of plugins). Every once in a while, I get the need for creating a Javax interface. To do this normally, I would setup the new java project then add what I need. But, wouldn't it be nice if I could just make a template project to automatically include the code for the files. How would I go about doing this? It it even possible? The Eclipse CDT can make a new project type. So can the Google ADT and Google App engine. So I would imagine it is possible. But how?

Comment: Did you find any solution or idea? Would you like to share it with us?

Answer (score 6):

You must write your Eclipse plug-in that implements `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point. You can extend an existing "New Java Project" wizard, and provide your custom project layout implementation (see the [API](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_wizards.htm)).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding java projects you might be familiar with maven. Maven offers of project template mechanism called [archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html). I never created an own archetype but the explanation to do this ([Guide to Creating Archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html)) does not seems to be so complicated.

So although this is not a special eclipse solution it might be helpful for you. Together with the [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin it also works nice together with eclipse.