# multiple file creation in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to create an option which would create multiple files in eclipse. For Example:-

I want to create an option "create module" which would ask user to specify package name. once user has specified package name it would create following inside that package with some specified format for each

1. a controller named Controller
2. a service interface named Service
3. a serviceImplemenation named ServiceImpl
4. a model package
5. a dao package

Comment: Absolutely possible....create a process having main method to do all these things...Inside this specify the eclipse's workspace as fiel path to create the folders. Assk the user for a package name. Now take this input and append to the fiel path to create a package. Once package created ur block of codes will create controller, dao etc folder inside it....

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what is asked here:

[Make Custom Project template in Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761943/make-custom-project-template-in-eclipse-ide)

Typically the build system, Maven, gradle, etc. is used to create and apply templates rather than IDE, but it is usually possible to create IDE plugins that would do something similar.

Comment: in fact I am using maven and it is a shared project. so how can i create templates using maven?

Comment: I have not created one myself before, but I have used them - they are called archetypes.  https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html